# DataStudio : YYYYMM giving the wrong month (MM) & year (YYYY)

Tags: looker-studio

YYYYMM, when converted into MM & YYYY, is refecting the previous month. For example - 202001(which is Jan 2020) is giving 12 & 2019 (that is, Dec 2019). What is going on ??!!

My data source is BigQuery where I have joined two google sheets on YYYYMM as the primary key - I created this by extracting year and month from dates of the two google sheet and concatenating them.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using complete `YYYYMMDD` Dates in Google Data Studio, as I haven't faced any issues with inaccuracy, using the `YYYYMMDD` format.

One way it could be achieved is by adding a fixed `Day` component to the end of the `YYYYMM` field, such as the `15th`; for example, where `YYYYMM` represents the current Date field:

```
TODATE(CONCAT(YYYYMM, "15"),"%Y%m%d","%Y%m%d")
```